# How to make a for loop execute faster

Tags: python

Trying to make the code below execute faster

```
def objects_to_binary_vector(self, object_seq: Sequence[Any]) -> 
 np.ndarray:
        binary=list(np.zeros(len(self.vocab)+self.start))
        for i in range(len(self.vocab)):
            if self.vocab[i] in object_seq:
                binary[i+self.start] = 1
        return np.array(binary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following can work:

```
binary = np.zeros(len(self.vocab) + self.start)
binary[self.start:][np.isin(self.vocab, object_seq)] = 1
return binary
```

Note: don't go back and forth between lists and NumPy arrays as in your original code. Once you have things as a NumPy array, try and use the NumPy functionality and stay with arrays.